# I am not able insert data in mongodb by nodejs. Please find below the logs of the error

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am not able to connect to mongodb and insert data into the database.
Please find the code below.I am getting following error in logs:: verbose stack at EventEmitter.(/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm lifecycle/index.js:280:16) verbose stack at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:213:7)verbose stack     at ChildProcess.node ./bin/www
    error Exit status 1
    error Failed at the firstexpressproject@0.0.0 start script.
    error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
    verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Here is the code::

```
var express = require('express');
var mongo=require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var assert=require('assert');
var router = express.Router();
var url='mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test';
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {        
res.render('index');
});


    router.post('/submit',function(req,res,next){
    req.check('email','Invalid email Address').isEmail();
    req.check('password','Password is 
    invalid').isLength({min:4}).equals(req.body.confirmPassword);
    var errors=req.validationErrors();
    if(errors)
    {
        req.session.errors=errors;
        req.session.success=false;
    }
    else
    {
        req.session.success=true;
    }
    res.redirect('/');
});

router.post('/insert',function(req,res,next)
{
    //res.redirect('index');
    var item = { 
        title:req.body.title,
        content:req.body.content,
        author:req.body.author
    };
    mongo.connect(url,function(error,db)
    {
        assert.equal(null,err);
        db.collection('user-data').insertOne(item,function(err,result){
            assert.equal(null,err);
            console.log('Data inserted successfully');
            db.close();
        });
    });
    res.redirect('/');
});

router.get('/get-data',function(req,res,next)
{
    var resultArray=[];
    mongo.connect(url,function(err,db)
    {
        assert.equal(null,err);
        var cursor=db.collection('user-data').find();
        cursor.forEach(function(doc,err)
        {
            assert.equal(null,err);
            resultArray.push(doc);
        },function()
        {
            db.close();
            res.render('index',{items:resultArray});
        });
    });
});
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: You, most likely, have an error on your script. If you want help, I suggest you paste it on the post.

Comment: Here is the code which you needed.Please help

Comment: In the `router.post('/insert',...)` function, you are supposed to put the `res.redirect` callback inside the mongo insert callback (just after the `db.close` statement). Also, which request did you make to get that error?

Comment: I have a file index.hbs which is having a form whose action="/insert".So when i am clicking on Submit button it is going to this "/insert" router.I hope this is what you are asking.And i made that change but still i am getting the error

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss-typed a parameter name:

```
router.post('/insert',function(req,res,next)
{
    //res.redirect('index');
    var item = { 
        title:req.body.title,
        content:req.body.content,
        author:req.body.author
    };
    mongo.connect(url,function(error,db)
    {
        assert.equal(null,err);
        db.collection('user-data').insertOne(item,function(err,result){
            assert.equal(null,err);
            console.log('Data inserted successfully');
            db.close();
        });
    });
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

You are asserting for ´err´ to be null, but there is no ´err´ in scope, you should:

```
router.post('/insert',function(req,res,next)
{
    //res.redirect('index');
    var item = { 
        title:req.body.title,
        content:req.body.content,
        author:req.body.author
    };
    mongo.connect(url,function(error,db)
    {
        assert.equal(null,error); // fixed here
        db.collection('user-data').insertOne(item,function(err,result){
            assert.equal(null,err);
            console.log('Data inserted successfully');
            db.close();
        });
    });
    res.redirect('/');
});
```